# Global exception handling com Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou querendo usar o [Global Error Handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) com WebAPI 2.

Criei um novo projeto, dentro dele criei a seguinte classe:

ErroLogTeste.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace ApiTesteErro
{
    public class ErroLogTeste : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(context.ExceptionContext.Exception.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Depois alterei o controle `Home` da seguinte forma:

HomeController.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ApiTesteErro.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            int x;
            var a = "j";

            x = Convert.ToInt16( a);

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Adicionei o serviço no WebApiConfig:

WebApiConfig.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace ApiTesteErro
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Também tentei com `config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());` e não funcionou

Quando eu rodo, ele da erro no `x = Convert.ToInt16( a);`, mas não executa nada na minha classe `ErroLogTeste`.

O que mais eu preciso fazer para ele executar o log?

Comment: Adiciona isso aqui após registrar as rotas. config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());

Comment: Ja tentou usar `config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());` ao invés de `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());`

Answer (score 1):

Você deve registrar assim:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());

        ...
    }
}
```

Como você não mencionou nada, acredito que ficou faltando configurar [*trace listeners*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx). Simplesmente chamar `Trace.TraceError` não registra em nenhum lugar por padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona isso aqui após registrar as rotas.

Vai ficar assim

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace ApiTesteErro
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErroLogTeste());

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu não consigo achar essa classe `ExceptionHandlingAttribute`, qual o `namespace` dela?